# Right trapezoid with an acute angle $60^\circ$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$ABCD$ is a right trapezoid with an acute angle equal to $60^\circ$. Find the lengths of the height and the diagonals if the area of $ABCD$ is $2+\dfrac{4}{\sqrt3}$.

[image]

Let $CC_1\perp AB.$ Then $\measuredangle BCC_1$ is $90^\circ-60^\circ=30^\circ$ and if $BC_1=x,BC=2x,CC_1=AD=x\sqrt3.$ I wasn't able to find a relationship between $b$ (the shorter base) and $x$, so I decided to denote $CD=AC_1=b$. Then from the given area we have $$\dfrac{b+(b+x)}{2}\cdot x\sqrt3=2+\dfrac{4}{\sqrt3}\\(2b+x)\cdot3x=4\sqrt3+8\\6bx+3x^2=3\sqrt3+8\\3x^2+6bx-(4\sqrt3+8)=0$$ I don't know if we can use that, but I don't think so. I'm stuck now.

Comment: This problem has no unique solution. I can reduce the height and increase $b$, while keeping area constant. So you have three unknowns: height and the two bases. You have only two equations, one for angle, one for area.

Comment: The given answers are $2;\sqrt{\dfrac{16+2\sqrt3}{3}};\sqrt{16+2\sqrt3}$ if it helps.

Comment: Probably there is another condition which you have missed.

Comment: What does $S_{ABCD}$ indicate? Area? Perimeter? It's usually  better to put things in words here.

Comment: @Hipo where the "b" disapeared?